# How to use Dateset to feed array of data to inference with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow Dataset API, and I could not fully understand the simplicity of its design, so I need some help.

Here is a simple example

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[])
y = tf.square(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(y, {x: 2}))

# result is 4, simple
```

If I have an integer array `arr_x=[2, 3, 5, 8, 10]`, how can I use Dateset API to iterate the array?

I am trying

```
p = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])
d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(p)
d = d.map(lambda x: x)
iter = d.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iter.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(iter.initializer, feed_dict={p: [2, 3, 4]})
  while True:
    try:
      print sess.run(y, next_element)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
      break
```

But no luck, any idea?

Comment: Does the reply provided answers your question? If yes, accept the answer as correct or edit your question according to the extra info you need.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
arr_x = np.array([2, 3, 5, 8, 10])
arr_y = np.array([[0,1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,0]])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((arr_x, arr_y))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
sess = tf.Session()
while True:
    try:
        print(sess.run(next_element))
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

However, there are two things I'd like to bring up

1. I did not see tensor 'y' in the above code, are you suggesting? Are you suggesting "sess_run(y, {x: sess.run(next_element)})" ?

2. Can I batch dataset before sess.run?

Comment: Can you please update your question based on what is mentioned in the comment above?

1. There is no tensor `y` in the example: If I have an integer array arr_x=[2, 3, 5, 8, 10], how can I use Dateset API to iterate the array?
2. The output of `next_element` should be connected with the model itself, so the data will be dynamically fetched into the model.